# Mongoose pre remove - Nested references to same model recursively

Tags: node.js, mongodb, recursion, mongoose

I have a model that can be theoretically nested infinitely (although that would never be the case).  It all works great, however, when I need to delete an entire "path" and its children, and its children's children, etc... the "pre remove" on the model, only covers the first tier of relationships.  When the children are removed, it appears the "pre remove" doesn't fire.  here is the model, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
 * Path Schema
 */
var PathSchema = new Schema({
  parent: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Path'
  },
  field: {
    api: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
      trim: true
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
      trim: true
    }
  },
  match: {
    type: String,
    default: 'equals',
    trim: true
  },
  value: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
  },
  date_created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  date_modified: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  user_created: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  user_modified: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
});

PathSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var now = new Date();
  this.date_modified = now;
  this.user_modified = this.user;
  if (!this.date_created) {
    this.date_created = now;
  }

  if (!this.user_created) {
    this.user_created = this.user;
  }

  delete this.user;
  next();
});

PathSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
  mongoose.models["Path"].remove({
    parent: this._id
  }).exec();
  next();
});

mongoose.model('Path', PathSchema);
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out with a bit more searching.  I dont think it's an ideal solution, but it works for now.  If anyone has a better approach, I would love to reduce the calls if possible.  Thank you!

```js
PathSchema.pre('remove', function(next){
 mongoose.models["Path"].findOneAndRemove({'parent': this._id}, function(err, path) {
  if(path) {
   path.remove();
  }
 });
    next();
});
```